# Laravel whereBetween doesn't work. it shows?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am trying to get last weeks data from `leads` table but when I use `whereBetween` with two dates no data found and in if I use `toSql()` it shows ? ?

query is

```
    select `lead_type`, `email`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `job_title`, `company_name`, `website`, `time_note`, `update_date` from `leads` where `created_at` between ? and ?
```

but it should be

```
    select `lead_type`, `email`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `job_title`, `company_name`, `website`, `time_note`, `update_date` from `leads` where `created_at` between 2019-06-06 and 2019-05-30
```

Here is the laravel code

```
    $current=  Carbon::today();
    $start_date = Carbon::today()->toDateString();
    $end_date = $current->subDays(7)->toDateString();
    $leads = Leads::select($excel_head)->whereBetween('created_at', [$end_date,$start_date ])->toSql();
    dd($leads);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't go for the query contains `?` as it's prepared statments..

try run this.

```
$current=  Carbon::today();

$start_date = Carbon::today()->toDateString();
$end_date = $current->subDays(7)->toDateString();

$leads = Leads::select($excel_head)->whereBetween('date(created_at)', array($start_date, $end_date))->get();

dd($leads);
```

You must have to convert `created_at` with `date` field and then compare.

Comment: @Naim886 does this help? let me know if you have still problem with this.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the start and end date backwards.

```
whereBetween('created_at', [$end_date, $start_date])
```

should become

```
whereBetween('created_at', [$start_date, $end_date])
```

Otherwise, your query is basically doing this:

```
created_at>='2019-06-06' AND created_at<='2019-05-30'
```

which can't ever be true.